# Find all occurrences of list of strings in array inside a sentence, and replace everything except the first letter with dashes

Tags: php, regex, str-replace, sanitization

I need to find all occurrences of a array of strings (original $list has over 780 items) in a sentence, and replace everything except the first letter with html dashes.

This is my current code:

```
function sanitize($string) {
    $list = array(
        "dumb",
        "stupid",
        "brainless"
    );

    # replace bad words
    $string = str_replace($list, '&ndash;', $string);
    return $string;
}

echo sanitize('hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually dumb and stupid.');
```

This is the current result:

> hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually – and –

The result should be:

> hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually d––– and s–––––

Any ideas on how to approach this? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want number of dashes same as original word length -1 or just some static number of dashes?

Comment: @anubhava yes, number of dashes should be the same as original -1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex based approach using `\G`:

```
$str = 'hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually dumb and stupid.';
$list = array("dumb", "stupid", "brainless");

// use array_map to generate a regex of array for each word
$relist = array_map(function($s) { 
  return '/(?:\b(' . $s[0] . ')(?=' . substr($s, 1) . '\b)|(?!\A)\G)\pL/';
}, $list);

// call preg_replace using list of regex
echo preg_replace($relist, '$1-', $str) . "\n";
```

[Code Demo](https://eval.in/961174)

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/58Mgv0/1)

**Output:**

```
hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually d--- and s-----.
```

---

- `\G` asserts position at the end of the previous match or the start of the string for the first match
- `(?!\A)` is negative lookahead to make sure `\G` doesn't match at line start

---

**Update:**

As per your comments below you can use this different approach:

```
$str = 'word';
$relist = array_map(function($s) { return '/\b' . $s . '\b/'; }, $list);

echo preg_replace_callback($relist, function($m) { 
   return '<span class="bad">' . $m[0][0] . str_repeat('-', strlen($m[0])-1) . '</span>';
}, $str);
```

**Output:**

```
first <span class="bad">w---</span>
```

Comment: I added 780 words to the $list array (bad words) and it took this time: 0.032 sec real, 0.032 sec wall, 15 MB, 46 syscalls - sounds expensive in terms of cpu if there are hundreds of calls per minute but it's still the best solution yet.

Comment: I found a small problem. If I use this `$string='word'; return preg_replace($relist, '<span class="bad">$1-</span>', $string);` (i need a different color for that), the result is: `<span class="bad">w-</span><span class="bad">-</span><span class="bad">-</span>` - The result should be `<span class="bad">w---</span>` Any ideas?

Comment: Check my updated answer for an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `array_map` to generate an array of replacements with the first letter only and optionally a dash for each character that was replaced:

```
function sanitize($string) {
    $list = array(
        "dumb",
        "stupid",
        "brainless"
    );

    $repl = array_map("dashReplace", $list);

    # replace bad words
    $string = str_replace($list, $repl, $string);
    return $string;
}

function dashReplace($str) {
    return $str{0}.str_repeat("-", strlen($str)-1);
}

echo sanitize('hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually dumb and stupid.');
```

Result for your example is: `hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually d--- and s-----.`

Comment: your solution works, I compared with @anubhava's solution and that one is just a little bit faster. Perhaps the regex makes it faster?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace_callback` but you need to add backslash to each item in `$list` array.

```
function sanitize($string) {
    $list = array(
        "/dumb/",
        "/stupid/",
        "/brainless/"
    );

    # replace bad words
    $string = preg_replace_callback($list,
        function ($matches) {
            return preg_replace('/\B./', '-', $matches[0]);
        }, 
        $string);
    return $string;
}

echo sanitize('hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually dumb and stupid.');
```

Output:

```
hello, i think you are not intelligent, you are actually d--- and s-----.
```

[Code demo](https://ideone.com/GioI2c)

Comment: It works, but adding a slash to each item seems extra work (the final $list array has over 780 items). Also it takes more time to run than @anubhava's solution.

Comment: @andufo I agree with you, but there will be problems like bad word `ass` and word `*ass*ociation`...I would go with adding backslashes and word boundaries `\b` for better accuracy.

Comment: It's kind of tricky. Some people can also use combinations such as `asswise` or `assface` ... the list is endless. I'll have to sacrifice `association` and other similar words because of that.